# In R when I use as.factor to change a variable from INT to Factor, it still shows "int" in the str()

Tags: r, variables, dataframe, type-conversion

The title pretty much explains my dilemma. But for further insight, here's some additional information: The code to convert the INT into a factor was:

```
x<-as.factor(dataset$x)
```

In the Global Environment window, it does show as

```
x    Factor w/ 2 levles "0","1"...
```

But when running the str() command, it still shows as

```
x:int 0 0 0 0 ..."
```

What step am I missing to make the change permanent within the dataframe?

Comment: You might just need `dataset$x <- as.factor(dataset$x)`. You have to assign the modified column to the dataframe, `x<-as.factor(dataset$x)` creates a new vector `x` that is totally separate from the dataframe.

Comment: If you are trying to change column `x` of `dataset` to a factor, use `dataset$x <- as.factor(dataset$x)`.

Comment: That worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

You have just created a new object `x`, I am assuming that you want the factor `x` to remain within `dataset`. The original dataset was not modified since you didn't overwrite it.

Try `dataset$x <- as.factor(dataset$x)`.